# Delivery Report From Twilio Rest Api using Java

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, sms, twilio

I am trying to get Report weather the receiver got the SMS or Not ?
I am able to send SMS but Twilio doesn't not call back URL that I have specified 
Following is my code snippet :-

```
// Create a rest client
  TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(com.main.Constants.ACCOUNT_SID,                    com.main.Constants.AUTH_TOKEN);

 // Get the main account (The one we used to authenticate the client
   Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();

 // Get all accounts including sub accounts
  AccountList accountList = client.getAccounts();

  // Send an sms
  SmsFactory smsFactory = mainAccount.getSmsFactory();
  Map<String, String> smsParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
  smsParams.put("To", number); // Replace with a valid phone

  // number in your account
  smsParams.put("From", com.main.Constants.FROM); // Replace with a valid                                   

  smsParams.put("StatusCallback", com.main.Constants.CALLBACKURL);

  smsParams.put("Body", "Token : " + token);

  sms = smsFactory.create(smsParams);
```

Comment: Hi, The callback URL should be getting hit with the SMS status. Can you verify the callback URL is not being hit, by setting it to a site that can check incoming HTTP requests, such as http://uncurler.heroku.com/?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio should make a request to the [callback URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional) with the status of the SMS message.

Can you verify the callback URL is not actually being hit, by setting it to a site that can check incoming HTTP requests, such as http://uncurler.heroku.com/ and sending a test SMS? Then refresh your sample page on Uncurler and look for inbound HTTP requests.

Another possibility is your outbound SMS messages are being rejected, so Twilio is never queueing the message for delivery. Check for exceptions being raised by the smsFactory.create() line, and check the error message there.

Comment: good answer So +1,can you please how to use http://uncurler.heroku.com/ >i am also using twilio for sending sms and wanted to know whther SMS has reached or not at the destination